# Meaning of notations like _NAME, __NAME, _NAME_, __NAME__

Tags: c#, c++, c

I've seen this in countless C/C++ header and source files.
Apart from personal preference, what's the meaning of each of these different notations?

- `_NAME`
- `__NAME`
- `_NAME_`
- `__NAME__`
- `NAME_t`

Quite honestly, the only one I comprehend is `_NAME`, which is a private member of a class (at least in C# it is).

Can someone explain the difference among them?
And if there are any other noticeable notations as such, please mention them (even in other similar languages).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Names that begin with `_` or `__` are typically for reserved identifiers, and you should not define/create identifiers that begin with that convention. (_ with Upper Case following)

From C99 standard, 7.1.3 - "Reserved Identifiers"

> — All identiﬁers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>   underscore are always reserved for any use.
>
> — All identiﬁers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identiﬁers
>   with ﬁle scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

From C++03 Standard (amendment to C++98), section 17.4.3.1.2 - "Global Names"

> — Each name that contains a double underscore (_  _) or begins with an underscore followed by an upper-
>   case letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
>
> — Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
>   global namespace

Answer (score 5):

Except for `NAME_t`, all of these names are reserved for "the implementation", that is, the standard C++ library code. **You are forbidden to use such names in your own code**.

Section 17.6.3.3.2 "Global names" §1 states:

> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

(Note that these rules forbid header guards like `__MY_FILE_H` which I have seen quite often.)

Comment: Just to make it more clear: at class level names beginning with an underscore *are* permitted (since they are not in the global namespace), and are often used for private fields.

Comment: @Matteo: as long as the second character is not an uppercase letter, this is correct. But `_[A-Z_]+` are completely reserved.

Comment: @R.: yes, you're right, the other answer is more complete in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

Types ending in `_t` are [reserved](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html) by POSIX.