# Is using __cplusplus undefined behaviour in C?

Tags: c

Modern C++ compilers are required by the standard to `#define` the macro `__cplusplus`.

This is often used in files that can be used by both C and C++ but the implementation differs slightly.

But in C (and C++ for that matter), the behaviour on using any double underscore in an identifier is undefined!

So therefore, if a C compiler sees something like

`#ifdef __cplusplus`

then is the behaviour undefined?

Comment: Why should the behaviour be undefined?

Comment: Because it contains a double underscore.

Comment: I didn't. Someone else did.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I added the C++ tag, because it is somewhat C++ related after all.

Comment: Why would the standard define something that you couldn't ever use? Makes no sense.

Comment: Using __variable is discouraged as it is supposed to be used by implementation. Using  __cplusplus is fine

Comment: It's not _undefined_.... such identifier names are _reserved_... https://stackoverflow.com/a/25090719/1347519

Comment: @MichaelWalz IMHO, C is suffice...but if you feel..it's OK.

Comment: It's always valid to check if any macro is defined.

Comment: From what I've observed, putting C and C++ together can incite the wrath of the downvoters. I was careful to only tag the principal language I was concerned with, and explain the relevant parts of the C++ in the actual question. I've put it back.

Comment: Writing code which will compiler as C and C++ correctly is pretty challenging and not really a good idea, there are way too many differences (VLAs, `const` and many more subtles). `__cplusplus`` and some other macros should only be used in (implementation) headers to allow using C functions in C++ compilation units.

Comment: If this was _UB_, how should anyone ever use `__FUNCTION__`, `__LINE__` or similar predefined macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using such names for *creating your own macros or identifiers* invokes undefined behavior. C11 7.1.3 (emphasis mine):

> 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>   1
>   Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and optionally
>   declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future
>   library directions subclause and identifiers which are always reserved
>   either for any use or for use as file scope identifiers.
>   **— All
>   identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase
>   letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.**
>   ...
>
> 2 No other identifiers are reserved.
>   If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which
>   it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, **the behavior is undefined**.

However, you are of course always free to *use* the macros/identifiers provided by the compiler/lib, given that they are made available in a scope you are supposed to have access to.

Answer (score 8):

> But in C (and C++ for that matter), the behaviour on using any double underscore in an identifier is undefined!

You're mixing things up. It's not *undefined behavior to use one*, it's just that the names are reserved. The key point is you can't *define some yourself*, but it's fine to use them.

From ISO 9899:2011:

> 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.

Comment: @WillyWonka To extend on this: Even if such an identifier was defined by a C implementation, there are two possible cases: as an identifier of the core language: `#ifdef` is a preprocessor directive, so it will fail. If it is defined as a macro, `#ifdef` will succeed, hence the guarded part will be processed. That could indeed result in problems; I'm afraid you have to rely this specific (and some other) names are used reasonably by the implementer.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding part from the standard is(emphasis mine):

> 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> 1
> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated **future library directions subclause and identifiers which are always reserved** either for any use or for use as file scope identifiers.

So a little bit contrary to what Ven posted, this is an implicit requirement to not use them at all, since they are also reserved for future purposes.

This is also stated more strict under section 2 of 7.1.3:

> No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

So they are strictly reserved for future implementations, which for example `__cplusplus` is making use of, as the first rule that defines what is reserved states:

> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.

But since your example is implemented by the standard by using an identifier from that mentioned reserved spectrum it is fine.

Additionally the example you are giving is actually not declaring/defining an identifier but checking if there is a preprocessing token(macro) is defined with the name `__cplusplus` what would be totally ok by means of the C standard aswell, since its checking if it exists, not declaring anything.
If you would have defined it your self, it would be not strictly respecting the C standard and cause possible undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no undefined behaviour in this case.  Undefined behaviour means the compiler makers are free of doing whatever they want with the affected resources.  This means you are free (in this context) to define new non clashing underscored identifiers to be accepted in the two languages the compiler is able to implement.  Think that the internals of the standard libraries implementations of compiler libraries can be full of such *undefined behaviours* as far as the compiler behaves correctly in the *defined behaviour* part.  In the case commented, the macro `__cplusplus` is defined **ONLY** in C++ (by the compiler itself), and it is as a preprocessor flag to indicate that you are compiling a c++ source.  Putting it between the `#ifndef __cplusplus` and the following `#endif` statements, makes it to exclude for compilation the in between code (normally, because it would lead to a syntactic error or an unsupported feature).  Normally, you will find the following construct in some/many C/C++ standard headers in your system (so they can be used in both C and C++):

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
...
#ifndef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

to avoid the `extern "C" {}` construct, which is C++ specific, and would raise a compiler error in plain C.

## NOTE

of course, if you `#define __cplusplus` before including any of these files, you'll get your C compiler shouting at you about bad syntax on including such a header file.  You can try this yourself to see how it happens:

## pru.c

```
#define __cplusplus 20170301
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
} /* main */
```

and then compilation of this gives:

```
$ make pru
cc -O -pipe  pru.c  -o pru
In file included from pru.c:2:
/usr/include/stdio.h:159:1: error: expected identifier or '('
__BEGIN_DECLS
^
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:59:30: note: expanded from macro '__BEGIN_DECLS'
#define __BEGIN_DECLS   extern "C" {
                               ^
In file included from pru.c:2:
/usr/include/stdio.h:235:1: error: expected identifier or '('
__BEGIN_DECLS
^
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:59:30: note: expanded from macro '__BEGIN_DECLS'
#define __BEGIN_DECLS   extern "C" {
                               ^
pru.c:6:2: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type 'int (const char *, ...)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        printf("Hello, world!\n");
        ^
pru.c:6:2: note: include the header <stdio.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'printf'
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /home/user
```

Think that **you are never going to move the standard header files to another computer to compile your source code**.  Should you try this, then you would have *undefined behaviour*, but never while respecting the compiler implementation.  This means, you have to accept the compiler makers to use those *undefined behaviour* things that result in compiler implementation details, but **you cannot do that in *your* code** (at least if you don't want to fail into your program doing nasty things)