# Is this a valid way to return an iterator element and post-increment?

Tags: c++, iterator

My class (let's call it `A`) takes in a `string::iterator` and it implements two methods:

- `auto peek() const -> const char &`: Returns a reference to the data at the current position.
- `auto get() -> const char &`: Returns a reference to the data at the current position *then increments the position.*

The solution I have come up with is the following:

```cpp
class A {
  std::string::iterator _s;

public:
  A() = delete;

  explicit A(std::string::iterator s) : _s(s) {}

  auto peek() const -> const char & {
    return *_s;
  }

  auto get() -> const char & {
    return *(_s++);  // <-- valid?
  }
};
```

In this case, I understand returning a temporary copy of the value would also work since `char` is small enough in size:

```cpp
auto get2() -> char {
  const auto c = *_s;
  _s++;
  return c;
}
```

However, say the data was sufficiently large enough such that I wanted to return a reference instead of copying. Would the following code be a valid way of doing this in C++?

```cpp
auto get() -> const char & {
  return *(_s++);
}
```

Comment: Be careful about variable names starting with underscores: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25090719/1643973

Comment: Do note you don't have a good way of checking `_s` against `string.end()`. Also maybe considering using `string::const_iterator` instead of `string::iterator`

Comment: @jjramsey thank you I was not aware of this until now. Will keep in mind going forward!

Comment: @Ranoiaetep yes those are some good tips, thank you! I have since made it a `const_iterator` and checked for `end()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `return *(_s++);` is perfectly valid and safe, provided `s` is a valid iterator to begin with (ie, the `string` is alive, and `s` is within the `string`'s valid iterator range).

`_s++` will increment `s`, returning a new `iterator` that is a *copy* of `s` before it was incremented.

Then `*` dereferences that *copied* `iterator`, yielding a non-const `char&` reference to the `char` that `s` originally referred to within the `string`.

You then `return` that reference as-is to the caller as a `const char&` reference, which is perfectly fine.

Even if you did not want to trust this logic, your approach to use a local variable is fine, and you can return a reference by simply declaring that variable as a reference rather than a value, eg:

```cpp
auto get() -> const char & {
  const char &c = *_s;
  ++_s;
  return c;
}
```

Comment: The key part being that the temporary isn't the char, it's the iterator. My mistake came from missing that detail.

Comment: Perfectly valid and safe for string and any other BidirectionalIterator or ForwardIterator.  The answer isn't valid for an InputIterator (the described sequence of operations would not be safe, InputIterator postincrement has to jump through extra hoops to be safe).

Comment: @BenVoigt an InputIterator is required to support the `*i++` operation with expected results. What it does internally to accomplish that is its own business