# Difference between INT_MAX and __INT_MAX__ in C

Tags: c, limit

What is the difference between the 2? `__INT_MAX__` is defined without adding a library as far as I know and `INT_MAX` is defined in `limits.h` but when I include the library `INT_MAX` gets expanded to `__INT_MAX__` either way (or so does VSCode say). Why would I ever use the `limits.h` one when it gets expanded to the other one?

Comment: There is some good information about leading underscores in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090635/use-and-in-c-programs).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should always use `INT_MAX`, as that is the macro constant that is defined by the ISO C standard.

The macro constant `__INT_MAX__` is not specified by ISO C, so it should not be used, if you want your code to be [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability). That macro is simply an implementation detail of the compiler that you are using. Other compilers will probably not define that macro, and will implement `INT_MAX` in some other way.

Answer (score 44):

`__INT_MAX__` is an implementation defined macro, which means not all systems may have it.  In particular, GCC defines this macro but MSVC does not.

On the other hand, `INT_MAX` is defined by the C standard and is guaranteed to be present in `limits.h` for any conforming compiler.

So for portability, use `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Clang also defines __INT_MAX__, as part of its "Works a lot like GCC" functionality,

Comment: I think that’s more “works like a c compiler” -)

Comment: @gnasher729: I think John Dallman wrote __INT_MAX__ (with leading and trailing underscores) but he meant `__INT_MAX__` (with enclosing back-ticks) instead.

Comment: __test_with_leading_and_trailing_underscores__

Comment: One *could* also use backslashes: `\_\_INT_MAX\_\_` ⇒ \_\_INT_MAX\_\_, or even `_\_INT_MAX_\_` ⇒ _\_INT_MAX_\_.  But, yeah, since we’re talking about code, we should use code formatting.

Answer (score 15):

> Why would I ever use the limits.h one when it gets expanded to the other one?

[`limits.h` is standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.10) and portable.

Every implementation of the C language is free to create the value of macros such as `INT_MAX` as it sees fit.  The `__INT_MAX__` value you are seeing is an artifact of your particular compiler, and maybe even the particular version of the compiler you're using.

Answer (score 11):

To add to the other answers, when you're writing code that will be run on several platforms, it *really* pays to stick to the standards. If you don't, when a new platform comes along, you have a lot of work to do adapting it, and the best way to do that is usually to change it conform to the standard. This work is very dull and uninteresting, and well worth avoiding by doing things right to start with.

I work on a mathematical modeller that was originally written in the 1980s on [VAX/VMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS), and in its early days supported several 68000 platforms, including [Apollo/Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo/Domain). Nowadays, it runs on 64-bit Windows, Linux, macOS, Android and iOS, none of which *existed* when it was created.

Answer (score 1):

`__INT_MAX__` is a predefined macro in the C preprocessor that specifies the maximum value of an int type on a particular platform. This value is implementation-defined and may vary across different platforms.

`INT_MAX` is a constant defined in the limits.h header file that specifies the maximum value of an int type. It is defined as follows:

```
define INT_MAX __INT_MAX__
```

The limits.h header file is part of the C standard library and provides various constants that specify the limits of various types, such as the minimum and maximum values of the int, long, and long long types.

The reason why `INT_MAX` is defined as `__INT_MAX__` is because `__INT_MAX__` is a predefined macro that specifies the maximum value of an int type on a particular platform, and INT_MAX is simply an alias for this value.

You can use either `__INT_MAX__` or `INT_MAX` to get the maximum value of an int type, but it is generally recommended to use `INT_MAX` since it is defined in a standard library header file and is therefore more portable.

Comment: `__INT_MAX__` is not implementation-defined. That term, in the context of C, means the C standard **requires** an implementation to specify what the definition is. The C standard makes no such requirement for `__INT_MAX__`. An implementation **may** define `__INT_MAX__`, but the term “implementation-defined” should not be used to describe that.

Comment: `__INT_MAX__` is a reserved name for the implementation's internal use; note the two leading underscores followed by a capital letter.  What you're describing is only GCC / glibc's implementation choice.  (Where they put the actual numeric constant in the compiler, instead of needing different versions of `limits.h` for targets with 16-bit `int`, or 32 vs. 64-bit `long`.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil what's the correct term for this concept? I would have used "implementation defined" to mean any feature a particular implementation supports and documents, not necessarily something required by the standard.

Comment: @PCLuddite: Mostly I would just avoid the specific phrasing “implementation-defined,” since the C standard uses it to mean things an implementation is required to define. I might say “GCC defines `__INT_MAX__` to be the maximum value of an `int`” or “Some C implementations define `__INT_MAX__`,” and so on. I am not sure GCC actually documents `__INT_MAX__` for ordinary programmer use. It may be something it defines for C standard library implementors to use in the headers, so they can write `#define INT_MAX __INT_MAX__` to make a header that adapts to different targets…

Comment: … In general, I might say an implementation defines something as an extension, or that is specifies a certain things, or other phrasing suitable to the particular issue. Just avoid “implementation-defined.”

Answer (score 1):

In the C programming language, `INT_MAX` is a macro that expands to the maximum value that can be stored in a variable of type int. This value is implementation-defined, meaning that it may vary depending on the specific C implementation being used. On most systems, int is a 32-bit data type and `INT_MAX` is defined as 2147483647, which is the maximum value that can be stored in a 32-bit, two's complement integer.

On the other hand, `__INT_MAX__` is a predefined macro that represents the maximum value that can be stored in a variable of type int on the system where the C program is being compiled. Like `INT_MAX`, the value of `__INT_MAX__` is implementation-defined and may vary depending on the specific C implementation being used. However, `__INT_MAX__` is set by the compiler during compilation, whereas `INT_MAX` is typically defined in a header file (e.g., **limits.h**) and included in the program at runtime.

In general, it is recommended to use `INT_MAX` rather than `__INT_MAX__` in C programs, as `INT_MAX` is portable and will work on any system, whereas `__INT_MAX__` is specific to the system where the program is being compiled.

Answer (score -1):

INT_MAX is a macro that specifies that an integer variable cannot store any value beyond this limit.

INT_MIN specifies that an integer variable cannot store any value below this limit.

Values of INT_MAX and INT_MIN may vary
from compiler to compiler. Following are
typical values in a compiler where integers
are stored using 32 bits.

Value of INT_MAX is +2147483647.
Value of INT_MIN is -2147483648.

Comment: Okay, but you need to explain how `INT_MAX` is different from `__INT_MAX__`.