# Can sized integer types be used interchangeably with typedefs?

Tags: c

Visual Studio stdint.h seems to have the following typedefs:

```
typedef signed char        int8_t;
typedef short              int16_t;
typedef int                int32_t;
typedef long long          int64_t;
typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short     uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
```

However, sized integer types use the `__intN` syntax, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=msvc-170

Is there any difference (for example) between using `int32_t` versus using `__int32`?

I guess I am a little confused if the purpose of the `int32_t` typedef is to be the ANSI C99 standard to abstract away the specific compiler syntax (so you can use `int32_t` in both Visual Studio and gcc C code for example), then I'm not sure why the typedef in Visual Studio wouldn't be: `typedef __int32 int32_t;`

Say that the codebase has the following:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    typedef __int64 PROD_INT64;
#else
    typedef int64_t PROD_INT64;
#endif
```

And it uses `PROD_INT64` everywhere for a 64-bit signed integer, and it is compiled in both Visual Studio and gcc.

Can it simply use the `int64_t` in both Visual Studio and gcc? It would seem this is changing `__int64` for `long long` in Visual Studio.

Comment: `int32_t` is a standard type, `__int32` is internal to the compiler.

Comment: `stdint.h` is provided by the compiler rather than libc or the OS. It provides _portable_ guarantees (e.g. `int32_t` _will_ be 32 bits). The compiler designers _could_ do: `typedef __int32 int32_t;`. Or, they can do: `typedef int int32_t;` The latter is what most `stdint.h` files do (since they don't have the `__int*` types). Probably, the VS compiler designers just grabbed a copy of the standard `stdint.h` and didn't bother to change it. Your point is valid, it's just a design choice (or lack of it) that the compiler writers made. Just use the standard/portable `int32_t` and don't worry ;-)

Comment: Historical note: `stdint.h` is relatively recent. In the 1980s, MS had [16 bit] MS/DOS. Many mc68000 based micros at the time defined `int` to be 32 bits. But, on the MS C compiler, `int` was 16 bits because that fit the 8086 arch best. `stdint.h` didn't exist back then. But, if it did, it would need: `typedef long int32_t;` because `long` was the _only_ way to define a 32 bit integer for the MS 8086 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sized integer types use the `__intN` syntax, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=msvc-170

Your wording suggests that you think the `__intN` syntax is somehow more correct or fundamental than all other alternatives.  That's not what the doc you link says.  It simply defines what those particular forms mean.  In Microsoft C, those are preferred over Microsoft's older, single-underscore forms (`_intN`), but there's no particular reason to think that they are to be preferred over other alternatives, such as the `intN_t` forms available when you include `stdint.h`.  The key distinguishing characteristic of the `__intN` types is that they are built in, available *without* including any particular header.

> Is there any difference (for example) between using `int32_t` versus using `__int32`?

- On Windows, `int32_t` is the same type as `__int32`, but the former is standard C, whereas the latter is not.
- You need to include `stdint.h` to use `int32_t`, whereas `__int32` is built in to MSVC.

> I'm not sure why the typedef in Visual Studio wouldn't be: `typedef __int32 int32_t`;

It's an implementation decision that may or may not have a well-considered reason.  As long as the implementation provides correct definitions -- and there's no reason to think MSVC is doing otherwise -- you shouldn't care about the details.

> Say that the codebase has the following:
>
> ```
> #ifdef _MSC_VER
>     typedef __int64 PROD_INT64;
> #else
>     typedef int64_t PROD_INT64;
> #endif
> ```
>
> And it uses `PROD_INT64` everywhere for a 64-bit signed integer, and it
> is compiled in both Visual Studio and gcc.
>
> Can it simply use the `int64_t` in both Visual Studio and gcc?

Yes, and that's certainly what I would do.

> It would
> seem this is changing `__int64` for `long long` in Visual Studio.

Which is a distinction without a difference.  Both of those spellings give you the same type in MSVC.

Comment: Oh ok, good points, and the very last sentence "Which is a distinction without a difference. Both of those spellings give you the same type in MSVC.", I think it basically the answer to the question: is there a difference? yes/no, and the answer is no. But I don't know, is there any more proof? It's kind of only an assertion.

Comment: @RichJahn, The Microsoft docs also specify [the sizes of `int`, *etc*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp?view=msvc-170#integer-types).  You will see there that `long long` is specified to be 64 bits wide (in MSVC).  I think that's as close to "proof" as the MS docs come.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Is there any difference (for example) between using int32_t versus using __int32?

A: Yes:

- int32_t and friends are [standard fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) (since C99)
- "__" is "reserved":

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25090719/421195
>
> C standard says (section 7.1.3):
>
> All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase
> letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
>
> All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for
> use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary
> and tag name spaces.
>
> What this means is that for example, the implementation (either the compiler or a standard header) can use the
> name __FOO for anything it likes. If you define that identifier in
> your own code, your program's behavior is undefined. If you're
> "lucky", you'll be using an implementation that doesn't happen to
> define it, and your program will work as expected.*

In other words, for any *NEW* code, you should use "int32_t".

Comment: Good points. Just still not sure about swapping out __int64 for int64_t in the existing codebase. That seems to be unknown territory.

Comment: Back at you - Good point.  If your legacy code uses "__int64" ... then the answer is probably "If it ain't broke, don't fix it." ;)  But the moment you need to *PORT* your code to a different (including "newer") environment, then you should probably adopt the "standard" typdefs (vs. the "legacy" #defines").

Comment: @paulsm4, `If you define that identifier in your own code, your program's behavior is undefined.` Does the same condition apply if I create my own new variable or definition (in the sense of using define preprocessor), will I still get undefined behaviour? For example, I define `__Hello_World`, which has not been defined by any standard library; so will I get undefined behaviour in the same as well?

Comment: That identifiers with leading double-underscores are reserved means that you must not *define* your own identifiers of that form.  It's an altogether different question whether you should *use* identifiers of that form that your implementation defines.

Answer (score 1):

From my top comments ...

`stdint.h` is provided by the compiler rather than libc or the OS. It provides portable guarantees (e.g. `int32_t` will be 32 bits). The compiler designers could do:

```
typedef __int32 int32_t;
```

Or, they can do:

```
typedef int int32_t;
```

The latter is what most `stdint.h` files do (since they don't have the `__int*` types).

Probably, the VS compiler designers just grabbed a copy of the standard stdint.h and didn't bother to change it.

Your point is valid, it's just a design choice (or lack of it) that the compiler writers made. Just use the standard/portable `int32_t` and don't worry ;-)

---

Historical note: `stdint.h` is relatively recent. In the 1980s, MS had [16 bit] MS/DOS. Many mc68000 based micros at the time defined `int` to be 32 bits. But, on the MS C compiler, `int` was 16 bits because that fit the 8086 arch best.

`stdint.h` didn't exist back then. But, if it did, it would need:

```
typedef long int32_t;
```

because `long` was the only way to define a 32 bit integer for the MS 8086 compiler.

---

When 64 bit machines became available, POSIX compliant machines allowed `long` to "float" with the arch/mode. It was 32 bits on 32 bit arches, and 64 bits on 64 arches. This is the `LP64` memory model.

Here's the original rationale: https://unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.htm

But, because of MS's longstanding use of `long` to be a 32 bit integer, it couldn't do this. Too many programs written in the 8086 days would break if recompiled.

IIRC [and I could be wrong]:

1. MS came up with `__int64` and `LONGLONG` as types.
2. They had to define [yet another] abstract type for pointers [remember `near` and `far` pointers, anyone ;-)?]

So, IMO, it was, in part, because of all the MS craziness that prompted the creation of `stdint.h` in the first place.

Comment: That's very interesting. I think what I always assumed was ANSI C89 was overly vague on integer type sizes, so then in order to support specific sizes, compilers invented their own syntax (but maybe that was entirely MS), then this is what led to typedefs with conditional compilation. And that's fine, it's just then ANSI C99 did the same thing, with stdint.h, although it doesn't need conditional compilation since it *is* the standard library packaged with the compiler, and then this is a competing system for doing the exact same thing, except it's ANSI standard.